# ProGuard in Android Studio

Tags: proguard, android-proguard

I am using ProGuard for my apps. Unfortunately, when attempting to release the APK for the 2nd time, Android Studio is giving me this error:

> Generate signed APK: Errors while building apk, see messages tool window for list of errors.

The first time I did this, I did not get an error. I have checked the sign directory. Everything is correct. I cannot release with `minify=true` for the new version. If I set it to `false`, it works.

Comment: Try with other KeyStore for test, and make sure that the password of your key is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem too, than I tried to make a new key store path, than it works, you can also place the key store path in the same directory as the last one you've made